# how to evaluate log traces based on time period

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataset of log traces, I need to view this according to per minute requests, I have transformed it in pandas like this,

```
   year    month  day  hour  Requests count
0   2018      6    1     0    114710.0
1   2018      6    1     1    115735.0
2   2018      6    1     2    130116.0
3   2018      6    1     3    133225.0
4   2018      6    1     4    128355.0
upto 24 Hour means whole day,
```

as we can see every hour has millions of requests, so I want to view it per minute I can use this script,

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df.date.dt.minute)['requests'].count()
```

then it will return 60 values, but the problem is i want 60 minute values of each hour with sequence so it become `60 * 24 = 1440` `requests per mins`  , any help will be appreciated, thanks

actual data has millions of time-stamped values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `date` column in sample data, but it seems need `dt.hour`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 10:10:12', periods=100, freq='120T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'requests': range(100)})  
#print (df)

df1 = df.groupby([df.date.dt.minute.rename('min'), 
                  df.date.dt.hour.rename('hour')])['requests'].count()
print (df1)
min  hour
10   0       8
     2       8
     4       8
     6       8
     8       8
     10      9
     12      9
     14      9
     16      9
     18      8
     20      8
     22      8
Name: requests, dtype: int64
```

Comment: yes, there is a date column , and I am waiting for output

Comment: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: valueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'

Comment: @KhanHassan - Can you add sample data with `date` column? You cannot assign to `df['count']`, because aggregation, need new DataFrame like `df1`